# Pandas category shows different behaviour when equating dtype = 'float64' and dtype = 'category'

Tags: python, pandas

I try to use a loop to do some operations on the Pandas numeric and category columns.

```
df = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
print(df.dtypes,'\n')

carat       float64
cut        category
color      category
clarity    category
depth       float64
table       float64
price         int64
x           float64
y           float64
z           float64
dtype: object
```

In the following codes, I just simply cut and paste 'float64' and 'category' from the preceding step output.

```
for i in df.columns:
    if df[i].dtypes in ['float64']:
        print(i)
        
for i in df.columns:
    if df[i].dtypes in ['category']:
        print(i)
```

I found that it works for 'float64' but generates an error for 'category'.

Why is this ?  Thanks very much !!!

```
carat
depth
table
x
y
z
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-8e6aa9d4726e> in <module>
      4 
      5 for i in df.columns:
----> 6     if df[i].dtypes in ['category']:
      7         print(i)

TypeError: data type 'category' not understood
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Try using `pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype`:

```
for i in df.columns:
    if pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(df[i]):
        print(i)
```

Or check the `dtype` name:

```
for i in df.columns:
    if df[i].dtype.name == 'category':
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
cut
color
clarity
```

## Explanation:

This is a bug in Pandas, [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16697) is the GitHub issue, one sentence is:

> `df.dtypes[colname] == 'category'` evaluates as `True` for categorical columns and raises `TypeError: data type "category"` not understood for `np.float64` columns.

So actually, it works, it does give `True` for categorical columns, but the problem here is that the numpy `float64` dtype checking isn't cooperated with pandas dtypes, such as `category`.

If you make order the columns differently, having the first 3 columns as categorical dtype columns, it will show those column names, but once float columns come, it will raise error due to numpy and pandas type issue:

```
>>> df = df.iloc[:, 1:]
>>> df
             cut color clarity  depth  table  price     x     y     z
0          Ideal     E     SI2   61.5   55.0    326  3.95  3.98  2.43
1        Premium     E     SI1   59.8   61.0    326  3.89  3.84  2.31
2           Good     E     VS1   56.9   65.0    327  4.05  4.07  2.31
3        Premium     I     VS2   62.4   58.0    334  4.20  4.23  2.63
4           Good     J     SI2   63.3   58.0    335  4.34  4.35  2.75
...          ...   ...     ...    ...    ...    ...   ...   ...   ...
53935      Ideal     D     SI1   60.8   57.0   2757  5.75  5.76  3.50
53936       Good     D     SI1   63.1   55.0   2757  5.69  5.75  3.61
53937  Very Good     D     SI1   62.8   60.0   2757  5.66  5.68  3.56
53938    Premium     H     SI2   61.0   58.0   2757  6.15  6.12  3.74
53939      Ideal     D     SI2   62.2   55.0   2757  5.83  5.87  3.64

[53940 rows x 9 columns]
>>> for i in df.columns:
    if df[i].dtypes in ['category']:
        print(i)

        
cut
color
clarity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#138>", line 2, in <module>
    if df[i].dtypes in ['category']:
TypeError: data type 'category' not understood
>>>
```

As you can see, it did output the columns, but once `np.float64` dtyped columns appear, the numpy `__eq__` magic method would throw an error from numpy backend.

Comment: would be interesting to explain **why** it works for float but not category ;)

Comment: @mozway Done! Feel free to check it out

Comment: actually, I am not sure the explanation is correct ;) my guess is, it's due to float being a native numpy dtype and category being a pandas extended dtype

Comment: also, string comparison seems to work fine `df['cut'].dtypes.__eq__('category')`

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one possibility in your list, go with @U12-Forward's solution.

Yet, if you want to match several types, you can just convert your type to check to its string representation:

```
for i in df.columns:
    if str(df[i].dtypes) in ['category', 'othertype']:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
cut
color
clarity
```